# how should I handle polling in ZMQ in node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, zeromq

I'm working on building a Paranoid Pirate in node.js. Starting with some python code:

```
poller = zmq.Poller()

liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
interval = INTERVAL_INIT

heartbeat_at = time.time() + HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL

worker = worker_socket(context, poller)
cycles = 0
while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL * 1000))

    # Handle worker activity on backend
    if socks.get(worker) == zmq.POLLIN:
        #  Get message
        #  - 3-part envelope + content -> request
        #  - 1-part HEARTBEAT -> heartbeat
        frames = worker.recv_multipart()
```

The Go sample code also uses a Poller.

The problem that I'm running into is that [zeromq.node doesn't seem to use Pollers](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/search?q=poller&ref=cmdform&type=Issues). Is the solution in node to just use a callback on message? how should I handle the `POLLIN` state?

Comment: My guess is, you are right. As node.js is well known for using event based model of operation, using callbacks for reacting to message receptions sounds very natural. In fact, it is not "missing Poller", but rather "implementation completed".

Comment: I suspect so but I'm drawing a blank on how to implement `socks = dict(poller.poll(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL * 1000))` in node. I guess I just don't need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poller is redundant in node.js.  It's all just callbacks on message receipts.  Using ZMQ in node requires a slight shift in the "traditional" ZMQ methods and architectures, because all of the built in strategies for non-blocking and event handling are offloaded to node, which deals with that stuff naturally.